# Angular 5 call AzureAD protected WebAPI results in CORS

Tags: angular, azure, cors, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

**Environment**

- Angular 5 frontend
- ASP.NET WebAPI 2
- AzureAD authentication on WebAPI

*Configuration*

- WebAPI is CORS enabled for everyone (***)
- AzureAD is OAuthImplicitFlow as enabled
- Angular and WebAPI are hosted in same IIS, different ports

**Challenge**

When WebAPI is called directly via browser, AzureAD auth challenge works fine and call gets authorized. However when Angular calls the WebAPI, AzureAD's auth challenge throws a CORS issue.

The Angular app *will not* call Azure directly (via adal-angular), its supposed to call via WebAPI only.
Angular app is successfully calling non-protected GET/POST functions on WebAPI successfully, so Angular-WebAPI connectivity is fine.

(**Update 1** *Angular APP calls ADAL-ANGULAR to authenticate with Azure and get a token, then same token is passed as bearer to WebAPI*)

Any thoughts what I am missing out here ? Any specific code/configuration can be made available as required.

**Code**

*WebAPI*

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [Route(ApiEndPoint.AzureAD.GetMyProfile)]
    public async Task<ADUser> GetUserProfile()
    {
        ADUser user = null;

        GraphFacade graphFacade = new GraphFacade(this.graphServiceClient);       
        user = await graphFacade.GetMyProfileDetails();

        return user;
    }
```

*Angular*

```
  Authenticate(): Observable<any> {
    this.authServerUrl = "https://localhost:44371/";   // This is where WebAPI is running
    let httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    let authRequest = this._http.get<any>(this.authServerUrl + '/api/aduser/profile', httpOptions);
    return authRequest;
  }
```

*Error Message*

> Failed to load
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=fba45f7b
>   : Response to preflight request doesn't pass access
>   control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You expect to get redirected to the AAD SigninPage when calling /api/aduser/profile within your angular app?

Comment: That's the target, however, I may be incorrect in my design. Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how it works. The Http Client will **never redirect** you to a page (in your case the AAD Signin-Page). It only retrieves / sends content from / to a resource. You can perform a redirect using **window.location.replace()** but thats probably not what you want (the token will not get back to your angular application).

You need to choose a **Active Directory Authentication Library** like *adal-js* or *MSAL* (you will find Angular NPM packages for both) and configure the component with your AAD settings. Then you can challange the signin from your Angular client and request an **access_token** for your API. Now you have to pass the access_token in the Authorization HTTP Header with each request you make against your (protect) API.

Note that you should create another Application in the AAD that represents your Angular UI and grant that app access to your API.

Comment: I do not want the token in my angular app, the token is meant to stay within the WebAPI layer only. Will check MSAL based way and then update further. Thanks

Comment: If you protect your API using AAD Authentication you will need that token in your Angular app

Comment: I have now used the ADAL plugin and got a token and user's profile successfully. However, while sending this token to WebAPI, the WebAPI's authentication challenge (by Azure) again throws the CORS error (same as above) .... Do I need any more changes on web api side as well ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to add the URL of your UI to the Allowed Origin within the CORS settings (in your API app)

Comment: WebAPI allows everyone *, * ,*.. Angular can call the api where authentication is anonymous successfully. Here AzureAD is giving the CORS error

Comment: Ah okay, but then the error is not related to any client, its your API that has an issue calling the AAD -right?

Comment: Web API if called independently, can authenticate successfully via its own configurations. It only fails when called via Angular. Do I need to mention any specific configuration detail (either at code level or azure level) ?

Comment: Hm, sorry that is out of my scope then.

Comment: Update. I did the graph api job via angular itself using login via angular-adal. But the corresponding access token is not able to usable when sent to web api... The azure challenge again results in CORs

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? @NitinSingh

Answer (score 0):

For those who looks about msal-angular MsalHttpInterceptor.
I've made own implementation of MsalInterceptor to overcome issues with protectedResourceMap.
This is my custom code block:

```
// #region own workaround in order not to put every api endpoint url to settings
if (!scopes && req.url.startsWith(this.settingsService.apiUrl)) {
  scopes = [this.auth.getCurrentConfiguration().auth.clientId];
}
// #endregion

// If there are no scopes set for this request, do nothing.
if (!scopes) {
  return next.handle(req);
}
```

PS: Vote for wildcard in protectedResourceMap https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1776